# How to perform privileged operation like Finder using FileManager?

Tags: swift, security, nsfilemanager, appkit, authorizationservices

After launching Xcode I select **File / New / Project / macOS / Command Line Tool / Next** and run the following code:

```
import SecurityFoundation

do {
  // Authorize for privileged operations
  guard
    let authorization = SFAuthorization.authorization() as? SFAuthorization,
    let right = NSString(string: kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsAdmin).utf8String
  else {
    throw CocoaError(.fileWriteNoPermission)
  }
  try authorization.obtain(withRight: right, flags: [.extendRights, .interactionAllowed])
  defer { authorization.invalidateCredentials() }

  // Rename MyApp.app into MyApp-Renamed.app
  let sourceFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/MyApp.app")
  let destFileURL = sourceFileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("MyApp-Renamed.app")
  try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: sourceFileURL, to: destFileURL)

} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Unfortunately, this program does not work:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“MyApp” couldn’t be moved
>   because you don’t have permission to access “Applications”."
>   UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Applications/MyApp.app,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move ), NSDestinationFilePath=/Applications/MyApp-Renamed.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/MyApp.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x100617380
>   {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}

The app is not Sandboxed. How to fix the issue?

Comment: Works find with non-system apps. Tested with Xcode 11.2.1 / macOS 10.15.2

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for checking. Maybe it works without authorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‪If I understand correctly, obtaining an authorization does not elevate your process. You just get an authorization reference to verify it or for use with another API that would let you perform a privileged operation. Like launching a privileged process or passing it to a privileged helper tool.‬

[‪Authorization Services Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-TPXREF28%E2%80%AC)

Comment: How about an authorization right? I don’t understand what exactly happens when we ‘copy’ rights. The macOS is apparently asking for credentials, so how can we use them later? I just cannot believe that `SMJobBless` is the only way to perform a privileged operation. Is it?

Comment: @Vadim apparently only SMJobBless and deprecated AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges are suitable for such operations

Comment: I so hoped for magic… The most likely Finder uses a helper tool with root access, right?